# Get product attributes details in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce

In php I am developing a "single product page" where each field capture and display data retrieved from the database. I stumbled upon the 'product attributes' database field since it has stored this value:

```
a:1:{s:10:"pa_flacone";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"pa_flacone";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";s:1:"1";s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}
```

that frankly I don't know how to manage in order to extract values and replicate them on php dedicated field. It looks like a Json format. Any help on how decoding this information and report in php form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use WP dedicated function [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) as your string is a serialized array:

```
$serialized_string = 'a:1:{s:10:"pa_flacone";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"pa_flacone";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";s:1:"1";s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}';

// Unserializing this string
$data_array = maybe_unserialize( $serialized_string );

// Output for test
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $data_array ); echo '</pre>';
```

I will get this:

```
Array
(
    [pa_flacone] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_flacone
            [value] => 
            [position] => 0
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 1
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

)
```

---

But this is some product metadata that you can get unserialized, using [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function:

```
Set your product ID
$product_id = 40;

// Get the data (last argument need to be on "false" for serialized arrays)
$attributes_array = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', false); 

// Output for test
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $attributes_array ); echo '</pre>';
```

You will get the same output.

---

To finish you can get this data through the [`WC_Product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) object to use all available methods for this class:

```
// Set your product ID
$product_id = 40;

// Get the WC_Product object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Using WC_Product method get_attributes()
$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

// Output for test
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $product_attributes ); echo '</pre>';
```

This time you will get something a bit different. all attributes data are stored in [`WC_Product_Attribute`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html) objects and you should need to use the available methods for this class in order to access the data as:

```
// Set your product ID
$product_id = 40;

// Get the WC_Product object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Using WC_Product method get_attributes()
$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

// Iterating through each WC_Product_attribute object
foreach( $product_attributes as $attribute_taxonomy => $product_attribute){

    // get the name (for example)
    $name = $product_attribute->get_name()

    // Access to the data in an array of values
    $attribute_data = $product_attribute->get_data();
}
```

Comment: Loic, the application runs locally not on server. Does the wp functions  work regardless?

Comment: @Alex Updated my answer to something complete. It doesn't matter if it's local or not. WP works the same way on local servers too.

Comment: thanks for your helpful information. I am going to implement my script accordingly. Hope to find you available just in case.

Comment: @Alex you can message me here or contact me through my profile, if you need.